# Validar formulario com name[] e id iguais

Tags: javascript, formulário, validação, id

Tenho uma um formulário dinâmico, onde pode aparecer várias `textarea`, e por padrão, essas `textarea` tem o mesmo `id` e o mesmo `name`, porém, o `name` esta sendo enviado como `array` `(name="nomecampo[]"`).
Queria saber como faço pra validar todos essas `textarea` no *javascript*, porque preciso verificar se essas `textarea` tem menos de **10** caracteres.

A `textarea` esta assim:

```
<textarea class="form-control txta" rows="4" name="descr_icon[]" id="descri_icon" ></textarea>
```

E como o formulário é dinâmico, pode aparecer uma, nenhuma, ou várias `textarea` iguais a esta, e preciso validar no *javascript* (preciso que seja puro, não posso utilizar *jquery*) cada `textarea` desta, mas a validação é a mesma para todas.

Encontrei algumas soluções contando o índice das `textarea` pelo `name`, mas no meu caso o `name` esta passando como `array`, então não deu certo.
O que encontrei foi mais ou menos assim:

```
function validacao(nomecampo) {
    var total = document.getElementsByName(nomecampo);
    for(i = 0; i < total.lenght; i++) {
        if (document.getElementByName(i) < 10) {
            alert('Erro');
          return (false);
        }
    }
}
```

E na chamada da função:

```
<textarea name="camponome" id="camponome"></textarea>
<button onclick="validacao('camponome')"></button>
```

Mas como disse, isso não funcionou no meu caso porque passo o `name` como `array` (`name = nomecampo[]`).

Alguém saberia alguma possível solução?

Comment: "essas textarea tem o mesmo id" O `id` é suposto ser único numa página.

Comment: Por que não usar `class` em vez de `id` já que o `class` pode ser usado em mais de um elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chamada da função você tem que passar exatamente como está no name.

```
<button onclick="validacao('descr_icon[]')">Validar campos</button>
```

Na função você tem que percorrer os elementos e verificar cada elemento, pegando o elemento pelo índice do for.

```
function validacao(nomeDosCampos) {
        var todosTextArea = document.getElementsByName(nomeDosCampos);
        for (var i = 0; i < todosTextArea.length; i++) {
            var textArea = todosTextArea[i];
            if (textArea.value.length < 10) {
                alert("Não é permitido menos de 10 caracteres");
                return;
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Tinha tentando desse mesmo jeito, mas não tinha colocado a variável textArea = todosTextArea[i];
Funcionou aqui, valeu!